# Como receber um número X que vai de 0 até 10^100 em C?

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados

Tenho uma questão que pode ter como entrada um número X que pode ser de 0 até 10^100. Estou recebendo os valores/número de entrada como `char` para facilitar. Mas não dá pra criar uma string/vetor estática de `char` que comporte isso tudo. Como proceder?

Comment: Faça uma pilha.

Comment: `char X[101]; if (scanf("%100[0123456789]", X) != 1) /* erro */;`

Comment: Você quer dizer 100 dígitos, certo? 10^100 dígitos (1 [googolplex](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googolplex)) vai precisar de [`4 x 10^75` yottabytes](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log2%2810^%2810^100%29%29%2F8) de memória... :P

Comment: tens informação contraditória: (Título: até 10^100 digitos [0..10^10^100] é diferente de número Corpo da pergunta: [0..10^100]) (difernça entre um googol e um googolpex)

Comment: Coloque mais informações sobre seu problema, preferencialmente colocando exemplos de entrada esperados.

Comment: Obg galera!!!!!

Comment: acho que o maior tipo de dado que vc pode usar em c eh o "unsigned long long int" que vai de 0 a 18,446,744,073,709,551,615

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar uma pilha ou uma string dinâmica para comportá-los (com `malloc`). Dependendo do caso, vale mais à pena usar uma [biblioteca de números grandes](https://gmplib.org/) pronta do que criar uma você mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Que tal estocar progressivamente o numero em um double?

```
#include <math.h> //pow()
int c;
long double valor = 0.0;
double potencia_de_dez = 0;
while ( (c = getchar()) != EOF )
{
    //Incrementa valor com o numero de entrada 
    valor += double(c - '0') * pow(10.0, potencia_de_dez);
    ++potencia_de_dez;
}
```

Comment: o `c` **tem de ser** `int`! Alem disso `while ( (c = getchar()) != 0 )` vai, com enorme probabilidade, gerar um loop infinito. Substitui por `while ( (c = getchar()) != EOF )`

Comment: O exemplo dado foi principalmente dado para mostrar uma maneira de abordar o problema. Levando em conta que não foi definido o tipo da entrada, a utilização do **getchar** pode ser inadequada também.

Comment: O problema dessa abordagem é que desse jeito, `valor` é igual quando a entrada é 10^99 ou 10^99 + 1 — você só guarda os 53 bits mais significativos (o que significa que estamos falando de uns 16 dígitos, mais ou menos). Além disso, você está lendo o número ao contrário.